# Query a database with python pyodbc and export the results to a HDF5 file (memory error)

Tags: sql-server, pandas, bigdata, hdf5, large-data

I've been recently working on a data that's over 50 million rows and 40 columns. I used pyodbc and read in the data by chunks, which took almost 40 minutes. My team members use R (rodbc package) to read in from MSSQL and export to fst file. Then, for future use, they can just read in that fst file (The fst package for R provides a fast, easy and flexible way to serialize data frames).

However, I don't think Python works with fst files. So, after reading in the data using pyodbc, I tried to export the result into h5 file using `df.to_hdf('data.h5', ".\input")`, but ended up getting a memory error.

Any work around for this kind of issue? Are there any fst equivalent file types that I can use in Python?

Answer (score -1):

For people who are having the same issue, I discovered [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html) package which works well around big data and has almost identical syntax as pandas dataframe. Read more about dask [here](https://analyticsindiamag.com/why-you-should-use-dask-if-you-are-into-data-science-and-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=Dask%20can%20enable%20efficient%20parallel,would%20bring%20down%20the%20overhead.).

These are the scripts I used:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.dataframe import from_pandas
    
#Convert pandas.dataframe to dask.dataframe
df_dask = from_pandas(df, npartitions=3)
df_dask.divisions  

#save as parquet file for future use (faster read-in)
df_dask.to_parquet('./input/data pull.parq', schema="infer")

#re-read in the parquet file partitions as dask.dataframe
#One of the biggest advantages of parquet file 
  ##is that it has low storage consumption. 
df = dd.read_parquet("./input/data pull.parq/", engine="fastparquet", ignore_metadata_file=True)
```

Dask Installation: https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/install.html

Comment: Typically recommendation of tools, software or libraries are off-topic as question or answer. See [help/on-topic]. Such posts can be attributed as spam (if say you are the author of `dask`) or as opinionated solution that varies among coders.